# How can I overlay two ggplot2 objects from contsurvplot package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I have two plots that are generated from the `plot_surv_at_t` from the `constsurvplot` package. One is looking at the 5-year recurrence free survival versus tumor size. The other is cancer specific survival versus tumor size.

```
model1 <- coxph(Surv(Time_To_Recurrence,Recurrence) ~ Tumor_Size, data = data, x=TRUE)
model2 <- coxph(Surv(CSS,Cancer_Death) ~ Tumor_Size, data = data, x=TRUE)

plot_surv_at_t(time = "Time_To_Recurrence",
               status = "Recurrence", 
               variable = "Tumor_Size",
               data = data1, 
               model = model1, 
               t=60)

plot_surv_at_t(time = "CSS",
               status = "Cancer_Death", 
               variable = "Tumor_Size",
               data = data1, 
               model = model2, 
               t=60)
```

Each individual plot looks great, but I want to show the impact of size on recurrence free and cancer specific survival in the same plot. I've tried the `patchwork` package and am able to get them next to each other, but I have not been able to onlay them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential option is to pull the data from the second ggplot2 object and add it to the first ggplot2 object, e.g.

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survminer'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:survival':
#> 
#>     myeloma
#options(timeout = 6000)
#install.packages("contsurvplot", dependencies = TRUE)
library(contsurvplot)

fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = lung, x = TRUE)
plot1 <- plot_surv_at_t(time = "time",
               status = "status", 
               variable = "age",
               data = lung, 
               model = fit, 
               t=60)

plot1
```

[image]

```r
lung2 <- lung %>%
  mutate(CSS = sample(1:1000, 228))
fit2 <- coxph(Surv(CSS, status) ~ age, data = lung2, x = TRUE)
plot2 <- plot_surv_at_t(time = "CSS",
                        status = "status", 
                        variable = "age",
                        data = lung2, 
                        model = fit2,
                        t=60)
plot2
```

[image]

```r
plot1 +
  geom_line(data = plot2$data,
            aes(x = cont, y = est),
            color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This looks great! I ultimately figured out if you use the curve_cont function, you can get the datapoints for the curve and then plot them using geom_smooth, but I like your way more.